# Symfony 5.2 Multiple Entity Managers strange behaviour

Tags: doctrine, symfony5

I'm trying to use multiple entity managers as described [here.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)
Example code in controller where *$shop* variable holds the name of the manager:

```
    $rp = new RemoteProduct();
    $rp->setProducts(array(2000,2001,2002));
 
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($shop);
    $em->persist($rp);
    $em->flush();

    $repo = $em->getRepository(RemoteProduct::class, $shop);
    $repo->findAll();
```

Generates queries to both managers. Flush as a transaction in the correct DB, but select queries are executed in the default DB instead. Any ideas?

[image: Queries to both managers]

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: shop1
    connections:
        shop1:                
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            mapping_types:
              enum: string              
        store2:                
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_STORE)%'
            mapping_types:
              enum: string
orm:           
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    default_entity_manager: shop1
    entity_managers:
        shop1:
            connection: shop1
            mappings:
                shop1:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: shop1
        store2:
            connection: store2
            mappings:
                store2:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: store2
```

Comment: interessting :D 

Can you show us your doctrine.yaml?

Comment: Thanks.
doctrine.yaml added to question.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that big fat warning at the end of the documentation was ignored by me.
Do not extend repository class from **ServiceEntityRepository**

> In order to fix this situation, extend EntityRepository instead and no longer rely on autowiring: